# An Event Apart DC (Oct 24-27th): Who else is going?

Tags: discussion, conference

First conference with An Event Apart, here: http://aneventapart.com/2011/dc/

UX User Jared Spool (you might know him) is actually speaking. Hope to see some of you there?

Comment: so, how did it go?

Comment: I'll do a full writeup later today :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An Event Apart was slightly more design and content oriented than I originally thought - although the presentations by Jared Spool and Whitney Hess were focused on User Experience, they were more introductory than actual forays into the subject. Aaron Walter's discussion was focused on fast prototyping, which was a very interesting presentation.

Since I work on a CMS primarily, I found the presentation on adaptive content by Karen McGrane to be astonishing. It was an absolutely fantastic talk about content strategy - but again, this is relevant to me, not so much the UX professionals that are out there.

I was expecting more in-depth UX talk - I wanted to see some creative UX solutions to problems using new tools. I didn't get that. I got a lot of great information that is critical to my role in the organization, but I wished for more.

I'd recommend this if you're like me - a person that makes website with a user-first mentality. If you're strictly a UX professional, I'd say this doesn't particularly hit the mark.